# Driving MOSFET with high rise time and high gate charge

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, powermosfet

My subwoofer got blown every time I got it repaired. A pair of K10A60D MOSFETS  were originally installed by the manufacturer, but the service centre never found the original part and used the FTA14N50C as a substitute.  It got blown in 2 hours.  They used the IRF730 and it worked for a day and got blown.

I did some research and found exact matching MOSFETS but I am confused if high rise time and high gate charge would blow it again. Any suggestions? I am looking to use the AOTF11N60L.

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 &  \text{K10A60D}& \text{IRF730}& \text{AOTF11N60L}& \text{STP10NK60ZFP} \\ \hline
\text{Type} & N-channel &N-channel &N-channel &N-channel&  \oplus \\ \hline
\text{Maximum Power Dissipation (pd)} & 45W &74W &50W &35W&  \oplus \\ \hline
\text{Maximum Drain-Source Voltage |Vds|} & 600V &400V &600V &600V&  \oplus \\ \hline
\text{Maximum Gate-Source Voltage |Vgs|:} & 30V &20V &30V &30V&  \oplus \\ \hline
\text{Maximum Gate-Threshold Voltage |Vgs(th)|:} & 4V &4V &4.5V &4.5V&  \oplus \\ \hline
\text{Maximum Drain Current |Id|:} & 10A &5.5A &11A &10A&  \oplus \\ \hline
\text{Maximum Junction Temperature (Tj): } & 150C &150C &150C &150C&  \oplus \\ \hline
\text{Total Gate Charge (Qg):} & 25nC &35nC &50nC &50nC&  \oplus \\ \hline
\text{Rise Time (tr):} & 22nS &35nS &58nS &20nS&  \oplus \\ \hline
\text{Drain-Source Capacitance (Cd):} & 135pF &300pF(max.) &146pF &156pF&  \oplus \\ \hline
\text{Maximum Drain-Source On-State Resistance (Rds):} & 0.75 Ohm &1 Ohm &0.65 Ohm &0.75 Ohm&  \oplus \\ \hline
\text{Package} & TO220 &TO220 &TO220 &TO220&  \oplus \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: Are the FETs driving the speaker directly (class AB) or via an inductor (class D) or are they used elsewhere e.g. in the power supply?  Ideally we’ll need a schematic.

Comment: Most likely a class D amplifier, given the description in the [datasheet of the K10A60D.](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/408/TK10A60D_datasheet_en_20131101-317921.pdf)  The "Total Gate Charge" is probably killing the replacements.  That or whatever killed the K10A60D parts in the first place.

Comment: No, not directly its class D amp

Comment: onkyo658.tiiny.site
here is schematic. check diagram2

Comment: Check/replace C963. If the mosfets are not driven properly, they will blow up.

Comment: There are many 600V TO220 MOSFET, 300-400 mohm, < 20 nC, > 10 A with lower max power dissipation (23-27 W). They should work fine in your circuit. Inspect C956.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These FETs are part of the DC power supply and not the amplifier.  If you start running again, run for a little while and and see if the transformer or any other component is getting hot (immediately after unplugging it!).

The FETs blowing after continuous use probably indicates a heat problem - so I would pay attention to the mounting.  Since the original parts are in a flatpack (all plastic body) you should mount them to the chassis or heat sink with thermal grease.  Poor thermal conduction to the heat sink is a likely cause.  If the parts are well heat-sinked and are still getting hot, they are most likely not your real problem.

Be careful using alternate parts - the PWM signal will cause voltage spikes on the FETs well above the 325 volts coming from the diode bridge from line power.  Once the FETs hit their Vds (max), they will act like a Zener diode and conduct, clipping the voltage spike with the spike's energy being dissipated as heat in the FET.  Both replacement FETs have lower voltage than the original (400V is WAY too low in my opinion for a 325-volt line), and this would be my first suspect.

MOSFETs turn "off" more slowly than they turn "on."  If both these FETs are "on" at the same time, there will be a high-current spike (shoot-through).  There is a "dead time" built into your circuit, which allows a delay after turning one FET "off" before turning the other "on." The amount of dead time varies dependent on the combination of FET and drive circuit.  Shoot-through could also be causing your issue, since the IRF730 will take longer to turn "off."  I think this is less likely.

If you have a scope, check the 15V (marked on the schematic) to see if it is clean.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks.
I understood that problem seems to be with ON / OFF time of the MOSFETS.
But, I need to find the best alternative as Toshiba stopped manufacturing the OEM K10A60D.